# Emberjs toggle effect of dynamic data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I have a table loaded with dynamic data from an api. The `<td></td>` displays a company name and when clicked I want a div that has the companies information to be displayed. I saw a few examples and this is what I did:

Here is my handlebars:

```
{{#each m in model}}
    <tr>
        <td >
            <p {{ action 'displayDetails' }}>{{m.name}}</p>
            {{#if showDetails}}
                <div class="company_details">
                    <p><strong>Wesbite URL: </strong><a href="{{m.website}}">{{m.website}}</a></p>
                    <p><strong>Development Wesbite URL: </strong><a href="{{m.dev_website}}">{{m.dev_website}}</a></p>
                </div>
            {{/if}} 
        </td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

as you can see when you click on the name of the company the displayDetails action is called

here is my controller:

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    showDetails: false,

    actions: {
        displayDetails: function(){
            this.toggleProperty('showDetails');
        }
    }
});
```

This works great; however if I click the company name all of the company details are displayed not just the company I clicked on. I obviously just want to display the specific detail of the company I clicked on how can I go about this?

Comment: You need to add some sort of identifier to link the company name to its details. Right now you have the same property for all of your company details, so there's no way to differentiate them.

Comment: @Tatermelon I understand that, my question is how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property to each item in the model named something like `isDetailsShown`.

You can modify you action by passing the item into the method.

```
<p {{ action 'displayDetails' item}}>{{m.name}}</p>
```

In the action, just toggle the property of the passed in item.

```
displayDetails: function(item){
  item.toggleProperty('isDetailsShown');
}
```

Finally modify the if condition in the template to look like

```
{{#if item.isDetailsShown}}
```